# onClickListener trouble

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

So, I'm learning and developing a very small app with Android AIDE on my phone, I have code like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit1;
    Button btn1;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
  //Problem (this) from AIDE error info: Method 
   'android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)' in 'android.widget.Button' can not be applied to    '(com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity)'//
    }
    
    public void OnClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),edit1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
                
        }
    }


}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your activity have to implement View.OnClickListener interface

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}
    }
```

Comment: One caveat here: if you make the activity implement the interface, you'll have to process all events from all implemented listener interfaces in the same handler. OP's implementation uses a separate handler for each component/listener.

Comment: `this` still in red btw, with that code I uploaded.

Comment: @UuuUuu PERFECT!, okay, so what I have to change here are `adding: implements View.OnClickListener after the MainActivity` and put the `@Override onClick` after the `OnCreate` method. So my mistake was making another copy of MainActivity class.

Comment: it's safe, if you want to handle hold button implements OnLongClickListener then override onLongClick not onClick

Answer (score 2):

You know what `this` refers to, don't you? That's a reference for your activity, but [setOnClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) takes an argument of type View.OnClickListener, not your activity.

Look at the sample code from the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button):

```
     final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
         }
     });
```

When you create the anonymous inner class with `new View.OnClickListener()`, that anonymous class implements the `OnClick` interface.

If you just implement View.OnClickListener on your MainActivity, you'd have to change the way you handle events, and I presume you want to minimize the amount of refactoring.

Comment: I don't know how to use `this` that's why I ask about it. but it seems very complicated to use. So, I will use the simpler one like the one you provided.

Comment: @AhiungLim The point is that you don't have to use `this` at all.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is working (Tested)

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
            EditText edit12;
            Button btn12;  
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                
                edit12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
                btn12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                btn12.setOnClickListener();
            }
           
             public void onClick(View v){
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btn12:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),edit1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: also change `edit1.getText()` to `edit12.getText()`